# Protractor: Firefox browser opens but site is not accessible

Tags: firefox, protractor

**TEST DETAILS**
Firefox browser - 69.0.3
Selenium standalone - 3.141.0
Geckodriver - 0.26.0
NPM - 6.4.1
Protractor - 5.4.2
OS - Mac Mojave

**Conf.js**

```
seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',

directConnect: false,
multiCapabilities: [

    {'browserName':'firefox',
        'marionette': true,
        acceptSslCerts: true,
        acceptInsecureCerts : true,
        'moz:webdriverClick': false,
        'moz:firefoxOptions': {
            'args': [ '--safe-mode', '--disable-gpu', '--no-sandbox', '--disable-extensions', '--disable-dev-shm-usage']
        }
    }
],
```

Firefox browser gets launched, url gets entered in the address bar but the site is not accessed.
Tried with both seleniumAddress and directConnect

Comment: can you manually reach the page ?

Comment: @Infern0 Yes, I am able to access the site manually